# Why is Vakil's definition of "distinguished affine base" of a scheme not a base in the usual sense?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, definition, schemes

From Vakil's *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*:

> The open sets of the distinguished affine base are the affine open subsets of $X$. We have already observed that this forms a base. But forget that fact. We like distinguished open sets $\operatorname{Spec} A_f \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A$, and we don’t really understand open embeddings of one random affine open subset in another. So we just remember the "nice" inclusions.

> 13.3.1.Definition. The **distinguished affine base** of a scheme $X$ is the data of the affine open sets and the distinguished inclusions.

Vakil writes that this a "not a base in the usual sense."

---

**Is this not a base in the usual sense?**

> If $X$ is a topological space, a collection of open subsets $\mathcal B$ forms a base if every open subset of $X$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal B$.

Let $U$ be an open subset of a scheme $X$. Let $p \in U$. Then $p$ is in some affine open subset of $X$, say $\operatorname{Spec} A$. Then $p \in U \cap \operatorname{Spec} A$, which is open in $\operatorname{Spec} A$, hence $p \in \operatorname{Spec} A_f$ for some $f \in A$. $\operatorname{Spec} A_f$ is an open subset of an open subset, hence open in $X$. So, $p  \in \operatorname{Spec} A_f \subset U$.

Comment: A base in the usual sense requires that the intersection of two basic open sets is a basic open set.

Comment: @ZhenLin Can you point me to a reference? That's not the definition of basis I have. It seems you are describing the fact that if we start we a *set* $X$ and collection of subsets satisfying some conditions (one of them being the one you listed), then there is a topology on $X$ where the collection of subsets form a base.

Comment: @ZhenLin You may describing Lemma 5.5.2 here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/004O

Comment: @ZhenLin That’s already false in the case of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the Euclidean topology

Comment: I don't know which version you was reading when asking this question. I got a similear doubts when reading the context about it. But at the end I found I get it wrong. Vakil does not say it's not a base. In fact, his original word is (at least in the recent versions): "The distinguished affine base isn’t a topology in the usual sense — the union of two affine sets isn’t necessarily affine, for example." Hence he is saying it's not a topology, which does make sense. And I think that this sentence is really easy to read it in a wrong way and change the word "topology" to "base"(at lest for me).

Comment: Ah I saw the word again now (at the begining of section 6.2 of the dec3122 version), "We make this precise by defining what we will call the distinguished affine base of the Zariski topology — not a base in the usual sense.  This is a refinement of the notion of a sheaf on base." It does be exactly what Exit path answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As he says in the text, Vakil is describing a (non-full) subcategory of the category of open sets of the scheme $X$. Namely, he is considering the category whose objects are open affine subsets $U$ and where there is a single morphism $U \to V$ if and only if $U$ is a distinguished open affine of $V$

The reason this is not a base in the usual topological sense is because it could be that we have two affine opens $U \subseteq V$, with a distinguished affine open $W$ in $U$ that is not distinguished open affine in $V$. In other words, in the distinguished affine base we “forget” that $W$ is a subset of $V$. The upshot is that to construct a quasicoherent sheaf on a scheme, we don’t need to remember arbitrary inclusions of open sets.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to why this doesn't form a basis though. Even if we only remember the "distinguished inclusions", it looks like we still have that every open subset is covered by affine opens. No?

Comment: The set of all affine subschemes certainly forms a base. I think probably my answer is not very clear, but by remembering when one affine is distinguished open in another we’re endowing that set with extra structure.

Comment: Thanks. I think I see what is happening. Vakil is defining a sheaf on the distinguished affine base which is different from defining a sheaf on the base. When defining a sheaf on a base, we define a restriction map whenever we have $V\subset U$ are basis elements; on the contrary, when defining a sheaf on the distinguished affine base, we only define restriction maps whenever $V$ is a distinguished affine open of the affine open $U$.